# change tumblr layout theme with script

Tags: javascript, layout, tags, tumblr

I would like to add different theme designs to my tumblr blog. The design should change if I click on a tag. For example if I click on the tag "food" the background, the sidebar image and the font should change into a theme related to food. Since I don´t get nowhere if I try to change the tag site itself (tumblr doesn´t let me overwrite this side with a new page) I started to look if I could work this out with the script functions. I found a code which was close to that what I searched for and it worked (I only got to change the background thought because I could not find a way to change the sidebar image with this). With this code I installed a button which should change the theme and send you to the fitting tag site. The problem now is that the change of the site applies BEFORE I reach the right site.

For example: I´m on my home site and if I click now on the button for the tag “food” the design of the home site changes and AFTER THAT the tag site will load and the style is getting normal again. It should be switched. First load the right site and then the change of the design. It should keep the design aslong you are browsing through the tag related pages and should change back if you leave the pages. Does someone know how the fix this?

Here´s the code I found:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function changeBGC(color){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
//-->
</script>




<a href="tagged/food" onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#000099')">Click Blue</a>
```

*Update 16.07.14 after feedback:*

Here is the end of my code from the blog (I didn’t touch the rest of the code):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> {block:IfSoundCloudLinkForPlayer} <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/j8hz7jr/nqTn1t8gg/stratus.js"></script> {/block:IfSoundCloudLinkForPlayer} <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/79xqv9n/d4nn7c5ja/theme.min.js"></script> <script>$('#loading').hide();</script> {block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID} <script>
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{text:Google Analytics ID}']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script> {/block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID} <!--OO.TS.--> 

     <script type="text/javascript">

  var _href             = document.location.href;       
  var _primaryDir       = document.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  var _secondaryDir     = document.location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  if (_secondaryDir == 'test'){
     $('body').css('background-color','#C0C0C0')
  }
  if (_secondaryDir == 'test'){
     $('body').css('masthead-background','http://www.rexwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/landscape/sunshine/sunshine_5.jpg')
  }else{
     $('body').css('masthead-bg','#08298A') 
  }
</script>                           
    </body> </html>
```

I had been messing around with different parameters earlier but this is what it looks at the moment. The masthead-background was just a random picture I found in the internet. I tried different links but no one worked so I guess my personal pictures would not work likewise. Like I already said the only thing working is the change of background-color.

Comment: javascript does not maintain state between pages, you will have to store state data in cookie or localStorage

Comment: Sounds difficult. I´m not a pro in programming and only know the basics from school. And cookies and localStorage certainly didn’t belong to that. I guess I should let my hands from this before I mess things up. But thanks for your replay. ;)

Comment: Instead of attaching this to the button which will direct to another page, you could catch the url parameters of the current page and then set some css if certain matches are found with a default if no match is found, this is not dynamic though, you would need to know the tags in advance. I have done this using jquery. If this is of use, let me know and I can offer some more help.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have been searching for originally. The button with script was a "plan b" idea because I couldn’t figure out how to change this with simple css. I already thought of catching the url parameters myself but I couldn’t figure out how to do this. Could I have a look into the code you have been using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this page is working:

http://layouttestblog2.tumblr.com/tagged/test

It changes the background colour as the variable matches test.

```
var _href             = document.location.href;       
var _primaryDir       = document.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
var _secondaryDir     = document.location.pathname.split("/")[2];

if (_secondaryDir == 'test'){
   $('body').css('background-color','#C0C0C0')
}
if (_secondaryDir == 'test'){
   $('body').css('masthead-background','http://www.rexwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/landscape/sunshine/sunshine_5.jpg')
}else{
   $('body').css('masthead-bg','#08298A') 
}
```

So the first if statement works, because background-color is a css property. masthead-background and and masthead-bg are not css properties.

If you try

```
 if (_secondaryDir == 'test'){
   $('body').css('background-image','http://www.rexwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/landscape/sunshine/sunshine_5.jpg')
}
```

That should work

(Don't worry about test tumblr accounts, I have about 8 for testing).

EDIT

I made a mistake with my css syntax.

It should look like this:

```
body {
   background-image:url("imagefile.png");
}
```

Or (shorthand)

```
body {
   background:url("imagefile.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

So the jquery should look like this:

```
 if (_secondaryDir == 'bespoke'){
    $('body').css('background','url("http://www.rexwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/landscape/sunshine/sunshine_5.jpg")')
}else if (_secondaryDir == "tailoring") {
    $('body').css('background','url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Sad-pug.jpg")') 
}else if (_secondaryDir == "wedding") {
    $('body').css('background','url("http://www.vam.ac.uk/users/sites/default/files/album_images/56177-large.jpg")') 
}else if (_secondaryDir == "suits") {
    $('body').css('background','url("http://www.roopevintage.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/NHS-524-Tortoise.jpg")') 
}else {
    $('body').css('background-image','url("http://irishmarxism.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/default1.jpg")')
}
```

The final else statement uses a default image if none of the other criteria match, so this should work on any other page.

Apologies for the mix up.

You can see this working here: http://madox-test.tumblr.com/ check the page links on the left.

Comment: Let´s see…I think I´m confused now. So I can´t change something which isn´t a css property. Got that but shouldn’t the rest like the menu and the posts be also part of the css? Do I need another code for that (or did I just got the wrong names for the parameter)? 
                                                                    And as for the code you posted, I´m sorry but it´s not working. I already tested it out earlier. But I copied the code just in case but it still not works. It seems like it´s getting ignored or something. ;(

Comment: OK this is partially my fault, I got the syntax slightly wrong. I will edit this answer shorty, and send a link to a tumblr with it working.

Comment: Hooray! I got it to work :D ! Even thought it took me some time. The code you posted didn’t worked so I had a look at your link and noticed that the script of that blog had two lines more. I copied the whole with the additional lines  " $(document).ready(function(){ " and " console.log(_href, _primaryDir, _secondaryDir); }); "
And now it works perfectly. I even got it to work with different mastheads. I´m really happy that it worked out. Thank you really really much. I don´t think I would have got it to work without your help. ;)

Comment: P.S. It seems like only “one word” tags are supported. If the tag is made up of two or more words it doesn´t work. It´s not a big deal but I think it´s important to mention.

Comment: I think you can do bob+smith but that is still one tag, not sure about concatenating two tags.

Answer (score 1):

OK so based on the feedback in your comment, here is a system I use on my own (and other) tumblrs.

First make sure you have a link to jquery in your theme, many themes do but if yours doesn't add this to the head of the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now we can write some script to catch the url params.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _href             = document.location.href;       
  var _primaryDir       = document.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  var _secondaryDir     = document.location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  if (_secondaryDir == 'food'){
     $('body').css('background-image','path/yourimage.png')
  }else{
     $('body').css('background-image','path/fallbackimage.png') 
  }

</script>
```

This would check the secondary directory some.tumblr.com/tagged/food

If it matches food then the background should change.

You can then write an else if statement and add in more parameters.

Hope that is enough information, if you need more let me know.

Comment: Good stuff, though I would also mention 'traditional' URL parameter syntax `?cat=food&tag=` etc.

Comment: I've never seen that on tumblr, is it used?

Comment: Not necessarily on Tumblr, but everywhere else; this is a quite in-depth [article](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/) about URL query string params

Comment: Weird. It´s only working partly. It seems like the only thing I can change is the background-color. Other parameters aren’t working. I can´t add images or change the colors of other elements. I already checked jquery and tried different themes but nothing is working. I must have done something wrong, but I can´t figure out what.

Comment: You'll need to either add some more code, or show a link to the tumblr. There are other ways this could be tackled. i.e. write different classes which contain all of the background image info and then change the class name on the body tag according to the page. A link might be the quickest thing, but I would also post code to show what you've tried. You may have to code an absolute url for the images.

Comment: Hmm, I don´t know much about css and stuff so I guess it’s the best if I just give you the link: http://layouttestblog2.tumblr.com/ . This is not my main tumblr blog thought. I made this stupid little blog because I didn´t wanted to mess up the code of my blog while I play around with the layout (therefore it´s not looking that beautiful XD). So the posts are just random stuff. But I used the same theme I wanted to take for my main blog. The tag I was experimenting with was the ´test´ tag. Since I don´t have much characters left I will post the code I have tried as a upgrade in my question.